# SF Short Story Identification: Boy finds a cube, people disappear, and boy becomes cube?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to search back up a short story that I read on the web. It's about a boy who discovers a cube, and when he picks it up, strange things happen.

- Things randomly transform into other things, and people slowly start vanishing or transforming into objects.
- The boy is the only one unaffected, and soon the town becomes unrecognisably surrealist.
- One scene in particular involves the boy warning a girl not to ever touch the cube, which she obeys for a long time. Unfortunately, the boy returns home one day to find the girl missing, and a doll with her exact features lying next to the cube.
- Secret agents from the state arrive, and they take away the boy from his family and perform psychological tests on him for years.
- The opening scene was the front lawn/garden of the boy's house, and there was this line that kinda went "The box was just suddenly there" on the grass/path.
- There was some kind of town gathering going on (maybe a carnival or a garage sale) and the incidents started affecting the neighbours a little while after the boy picked up the cube.

I forgot what happens after that, but I remember that the ending scene is that

> the boy ends up in a small boxed space, and above him, another young boy peers down (hence looping the entire story).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When did you read it? What language was it in? Any idea of the nationality? What sort of website did you read it on?

Comment: Hey! I read it in English, but I have no clue about the rest.  Really sorry about that! The most that I remember was that it was a site with a pretty simple layout - I arrived at the story from a direct link rather than from exploring the website, which is why I don't have much information on the latter.

Comment: Well the plot summary you gave was very detailed, so hopefully somebody will know of it.

Comment: Can you remember any keywords or links that routed you to that site? What else can you say about that site (did it have a lot of short SF stories, the works of just one author, a lot of different stories that we not just SF...)

Comment: I remember reading something quite similar and the link to it came from here... but I can't find back the question/answer. It was a object/toy that the boy tried to solve and couldn't.

Comment: I really cannot give any more clues about the site, I think someone on a forum or reddit just shared it in one of those 'cool short stories' threads. 

I do remember more of the beginning though - The opening scene was the front lawn/garden of the boy's house, and there was this line that kinda went "The box was just suddenly there" on the grass/path. There was some kind of town gathering going on (maybe a carnival or a garage sale) and the incidents started affecting the neighbours a little while after the boy picked up the cube.

Answer (score 8):

That's "Deus Ex Arca" by Desirina Boskovich, available online in its entirety [here](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/deus-ex-arca/) or [here](http://lightspeedmagazine.kinja.com/lightspeed-presents-deus-ex-arca-by-desirina-bosko-461155580). Has all the elements you describe: the boy discovers a strange box, it causes strange transformations in others who touch it but does nothing to him, government agents come to investigate when he takes the box home, he tells his sister Emily not to touch it but eventually he just finds a doll in her place, etc.